# Compare elements of a list and apply conditions

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Using the K-means algorithm, I have classified daily company's returns into 10 (=k) groups. I've applied this process on each window (1 month) of my database.  Now, I would like to COMPARE CLUSTERS OVER TIME. In other words, I would like to identify which cluster of window t+1 corresponds to the first cluster (let's say C1) of window t. Then, which cluster of window t+1 corresponds to the second cluster (let's say C2) of window t. And so on for the 10 clusters of window t... 
The hypothesis I instore in order to consider two clusters as similar is the following: minimum 60% of companies present in one cluster at window t has to be present in the cluster at window t+1.

I have a dataframe (i.e. Df) of 4 variables (ie. WindClus, Window, Cluster and Company).

- *WindClus* is a concatenate of both *Window* and *Cluster*.
- *Window* is constructed as a non-overlapping rolling window; with each window representing 1 month.
- Each *Window* contains 10 *Clusters* (groups), and each *Cluster* gather several *Companies*.

See the url image in the following footnote to get a better picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZLeN.png).

How can I achieve a pairwise comparison of cluster ? and, in function of the result, change the cluster number in order to corresponds to the new one?

Answer (score 1):

K-means is randomized. It won't even give you the same result of you run it twice on the same month.

So do *not* expect clusters to have a 1:1 correspondence from one month to another!

What you could do is join all data, run k-means only once (or better, run it several times to check if the result is stable - very different results indicate that the result is not good!) And then split the data after clustering.

Comment: It helps, thanks. However, due to the fact that K-means is randomized, I planned to save K-means results in a dataframe (or set.seed)  so that it doesn't change anymore. Furthermore I do not expect a complete 1:1 correspondence but the most similar clusters. Do you still consider it is not feasible ? 
I also tought about considering clusters of Window t and Window t+1 as similar if their centroïds are the closest. However I do not know how to implement it. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: That only works for unchanged data. On different data, fixing the seed does not work.